# Ionic: Admob show on iOS & Android run from computer & testflight, but not on Google Play?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, admob, google-play-services, cordova-plugins

Admob ads show on my ionic iOS app run straight from xcode onto my phone and on Testflight link.

Admob ads show on my ionic android app run straight from my computer onto my phone, but not on the google play store link download?

Why would that be the cordova admob plugin and everything is turned on and set correctly?

Also I'm definitely using the real ad ids, not Google's test ids.

Comment: Did you check the ad ids before pushing it to play store. Make sure that you remove test ad ids and you put live ad ids, that might be the problem I think.

Comment: No I'm definitely using the real ad ids, not Google's test ids.

Comment: Have you taken a look at logcat? Maybe you can also try to upload the app with `android:debuggable=true` and debug the store app

Comment: Now it is even weirder it shows up sometimes and disappears other times with no rhyme or reason. Anyone else have this issue?

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I'm having similar issues.